# Why is CSS clear property not clearing floats?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have some very simple HTML and CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/79gdnyt1/8/

HTML

```
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/120x110">
  <span>This text will wrap around the image.</span>
  <span class="clear">This text isn't allowed to wrap around floated elements, and therefore will render underneath them.</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img {
  float: right;
}

.clear {
  clear: right;
}
```

Why is the element with the class `clear` not displaying underneath the floated image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clear` only applies to block-level elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

> **Initial value**  none
>
> **Applies to** block-level elements
>
> **Inherited**  no
>
> **Media**  visual

```css
div {
  background: #888;
  padding: 15px;
}

img {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
}

.clear {
  display: block;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/120x110">
  <span>This text will wrap around the image.</span>
  <span class="clear">This text isn't allowed to wrap around floated elements, and therefore will render underneath them.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: block` property in `.clear` class